# (Python) display newly arriving files in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, automation

What I'm trying to do is check a folder for pictures and automatically display them in a tkinter windows when they arrive in the source path. This is my progress for now:

```
source_path = r"C:\SOURCE"                              # Your Source path
dest_path = r"C:\Users\me\Google Drive"              # Destination path
file_ending = '.jpg'                                    # Needed File ending
files = os.listdir(source_path)                         # lits directorys in source_path
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')     # get the current date
sleepingtime = 1                                        # amount of time sleeping


while True:
    print("Beginning checkup")
    print("=================")
    if not os.path.exists(source_path) or not os.path.exists(dest_path): # checks if directory exists
        print("Destination/Source Path does not exist!")
    else:
        print("Destination exists, checking files...")
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(file_ending):
               #what comes here?

    print("=================")
    print('Checkup done, waiting for next round...')
    time.sleep(sleepingtime) # wait a few seconds between looking at the directory
```

- How do i make sure it doesnt repeatedly open a tkinter window for files that it already showed?
- how can i show them in a tkinter window

Comment: you can keep names of opened files and not open them again. Or you can check file timestamp and open only files with new timestamp.

Comment: To display image you can use `PIL`, and `tkinter.Label` - ie. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: BTW: you can't use `while True` loop with `Tkinter` because it blocks `root.mainloop()` and freezes all GUI. You will need `root.after(miliseconds, functions)` to run code periodically.

Comment: yeah but how could i implement this?#

Comment: [simple example how to use after to update time](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py). The same way you can use `after` instead of `while True`